# ')' expected. - VHDL

Tags: vhdl

A piece of my VHDL code is:

```
                133 if(grupo = '000' or grupo = '111') then -- 0
                                
                134 elsif(grupo = '001' or grupo = '010') then -- 1
                                    
                135 elsif(grupo = '011') then -- 2
                                    
                136 elsif(grupo = '100') then -- -2
                                    
                137 elsif(grupo = '101' or grupo = '110') then  -- -1
                    
                138 end if;
```

However, this errors came:

---

Error: COMP96_0049: Multiplicador.vhd : (133, 17): Syntax error in expression.

Error: COMP96_0015: Multiplicador.vhd : (133, 17): ')' expected.

Error: COMP96_0019: Multiplicador.vhd : (133, 18): Keyword 'then' expected.

Error: COMP96_0019: Multiplicador.vhd : (141, 6): Keyword 'end' expected.

Error: COMP96_0049: Multiplicador.vhd : (141, 20): Syntax error in expression.

Error: COMP96_0015: Multiplicador.vhd : (141, 20): ')' expected.

Error: COMP96_0019: Multiplicador.vhd : (141, 21): Keyword 'then' expected.

Error: COMP96_0019: Multiplicador.vhd : (147, 9): Keyword 'process' expected.

Error: COMP96_0015: Multiplicador.vhd : (150, 8): ';' expected.

Error: COMP96_0016: Multiplicador.vhd : (150, 10): Design unit declaration expected.

---

But I can't find a solution. The error is in this part.

Comment: You should *probably* double-check the number of open parentheses you have with respect to close parentheses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's probably more than one thing wrong in your code.  Just showing lines with reported syntax errors isn't always adequate.  Sometimes the actual error can be in a preceding line.

```
 if(grupo = '000' or grupo = '111') then
```

The lexical element `'` (apostrophe) is only acceptable to either indicate an attribute, indicating the target of a qualified expression or as part of a character literal.

`'000'` etc. are none of these. An attribute name is an identifier, as is a type name used to specify the type an aggregate should be treated as.

Should these be using parentheses?  (`"000"`, `"111"`, etc.)

You haven't provided enough sample code to reproduce the errors.

This successfully analyzes:

```
entity multiplicador is
end entity;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

architecture que of multiplicador is
    signal grupo:   std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
UNLABLED:
    process (grupo)
    begin
        if (grupo = "000" or grupo = "111") then -- 0

        elsif(grupo = "001" or grupo = "010") then -- 1

        elsif(grupo = "011") then -- 2

        elsif(grupo = "100") then -- -2

        elsif(grupo = "101" or grupo = "110") then  -- -1

        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just had to change '101' to "101", for example. The problem was in the single quotes.The strange thing is that I never saw it in a tutorial on VHDL.
Thank you.